# How are the Voyager spacecraft protected from hackers?

Tags: obscurity

I just read https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37980/does-the-voyager-team-use-a-wrapper-fortran77-to-python-to-transmit-current and it struck me: how does NASA prevent satellites like this to be hi-jacked? Any security protocol designed in the 70s should be broken by now, shouldn't they? Furthermore, the CPU and storage capacity of a 70s satellite should be too limited to apply some modern algorithm?

Or are they relying on obscurity: no one else has the means to build the large enough satellite dishes required to communicate with crafts this far away?

Edit: I don't need to edit it, this is very different from the linked question. You can't prove non-existence so if you claim that they are similar, you have the burden of proof.

Comment: How does one transmit to Voyager?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would one need to do in order to hijack a satellite?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/what-would-one-need-to-do-in-order-to-hijack-a-satellite) (except even harder to aim a dish at Voyager than something that's in a far closer orbit).

Comment: I don't think it's a fair duplicate. The targets are wildly different both in era and in distance from earth. It may certainly be off topic for other reasons tho...

Comment: @gowenfawr No it is not. The linked question relates to satellites with reasonably modern electronics which probably can handle modern cryptos (any $50 headphone can do it so it is reasonable to assume even a 15 year old satellite can even though they didn't use state of the art components when it was built).